# How to use bitbucket for lazy deployment

Tags: git, deployment, bitbucket

I own some software tools that are made up of scripts (no compiled binaries). I would like to store the scripts directly in a bitbucket repo, and then have a tool wrapper that will automatically deploy the version of the tool when a user first tries to access that version (via a git SHA or tag). We have some other tools that do this exact thing, but I'm not sure if they are doing it in the best way. They are definitely not handling race conditions and to make things simple, they are deploying to a scratch directory that is writable to everyone, which is obviously not the safest thing to do.

Does anyone know of any example open source code that does this sort of lazy deployment? I'm curious how other people handle this. Or is this sort of deployment just not something that people do?

Answer (score 0):

If Git is to be used as part of a deployment process, then said deployment can refer to a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**: by default, a Git repo would store only an URL and a Git SHA1 of the nested repo referenced as a submodule (your script BitBucket repo in your case)

Whenever the user needs it the first time, a `git submodule update --init` would be enough to fetch the actual content of the submodule repo, and populate it with the script.

Comment: I don't quite understand how a submodule would help here. I get that you can update the SHA1 of the submodule, but you could also do that without a submodule. I need to have multiple versions deployed on NFS. Multiple users would be accessing this and different users would need different versions.

Comment: @NathanPeterson A submodule is a combination of an URL and a SHA1. But only one SHA1, so *one* version, which does not seem to be what you need for your users.